# "for num in [1,4,5]" Python equivalent in C++?

Tags: c++, python, for-loop

Is there a direct analog to this in C++?

```
for num in [1,4,5] :
```

iterates through a loop using `num=1`, then `4`, then `5`. If I call continue within this loop it goes to the next number wherever I may call it.

Is there a similar structure in C++?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C++11, the following is legal:

```
for (auto num : {1,4,5})
{
    // loop body
}
```

`{1,4,5}` here is an instance of `std::initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: @Charles : Had to double-check the standard that a bare initializer list was legal in this context. :-]

Comment: Since this one will be more applicable as time goes on, I'll vote this as the answer (although Steve Jessop's answer below also works perfectly)

Answer (score 4):

In C++03 the closest equivalent would be:

```
int values[] = {1,4,5};
for (int *p = values; p != values + sizeof(values) / sizeof(*values); ++p) {
    int num = *p;
    ...
}
```

A common thing to define, which has been added to C++11 as `std::end` just when you no longer need it, is:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
T *endof(T (&ra)[N]) {
    return ra + N;
}
```

Then you use it like:

```
int values[] = {1,4,5};
for (int *p = values; p != endof(values); ++p) {
    int num = *p;
    ...
}
```

So for C++03 the short answer is "no", there isn't a similar structure.

Comment: This code worked for me -- thanks! I do not have C++11 so I was not able to use the other answer, but that is my fault for not mentioning so. Is there a way I can accept two answers?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian: you can only accept one answer. SO is supposed to exist forever, so the C++11 answer will over time become applicable to more people. It's worth checking whether or not you can use a restricted set of C++11 features. Depends what your compiler has implemented, and what your style guide permits.

Answer (score 2):

A `vector<int>` with its forward iterator.

**EDIT:**

Man, my C++ is rusty...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int ints[] = {1, 4, 5};
  std::vector<int> v (ints, ints + 3);

  for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); i++)
  {
    std::cout << *i << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an example of its usage?

Comment: Why create a vector and iterate over it, which you could have iterated over the array that you used to initialize the vector?

Comment: @Steve: Because it may already be a vector from somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, then we had different ideas what the questioner was asking. I thought it was relevant to the question that the numbers to use were specified in-place. If not, then it's worth noting that the pattern of looping with an iterator works for *any* range that can be specified using a begin and end iterator. `vector` is just one example of a container, probably the most commonly used.

Answer (score 0):

The similiar thing would be to create an stl-Vector of this integers and iterate over it with a for loop and an iterator. But it would not be a very practicle thing to do in C++, I think.

Comment: Iterating over a container in C++ is not practical? What?

Comment: @ildjarn: creating a vector solely for the purpose of iterating over a fixed set of known numbers, is not practical. You first have to iterate over the known set of numbers to create the vector, which in C++11 you'd do with an initialization list and in C++03 with an array. Either way, you can cut out the middle man and get rid of the vector.

Comment: @Steve : Between Boost.Array, Boost.Assign, and Qt's `QList::operator<<`, I think this is relatively painless; I didn't take the question to imply language features exclusively, but maybe I misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

[Boost.Foreach](http://www.boost.org/libs/foreach/) is something that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in Ignacio's answer, vector from the Standard Template Libraries is the way to go here. The first example at the entry at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/vector/) appears to be what you want.